# Where can I find any clue about how hadoop jobtracker stopped?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

The jobtracker stopped. I checked the log (hadoop-cmf-mapreduce1-JOBTRACKER-ip-10-0-2-91.aws.novarra.com.log.out). I can see it stoped at 2014-01-08 19:53:07, but there is no error message.

Where can I find any clue about how it stopped?

Thanks.

```
2014-01-08 19:53:05,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing data-local task task_201401030639_35091_m_000053
2014-01-08 19:53:06,238 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201401030639_35082_m_000072_0' has completed task_201401030639_35082_m_000072 successfully.
2014-01-08 19:53:06,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201401030639_35075_r_000000_0' has completed task_201401030639_35075_r_000000 successfully.
2014-01-08 19:53:06,242 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2014-01-08 19:53:06,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (JOB_CLEANUP) 'attempt_201401030639_35075_r_000003_0' to tip task_201401030639_35075_r_000003, for tracker 'tracker_ip-10-0-2-86.aws.novarra.com:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:54912'

2014-01-08 19:53:07,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201401030639_35106_m_000032_0' has completed task_201401030639_35106_m_000032 successfully.
2014-01-08 19:53:07,136 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2014-01-08 19:53:07,136 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (MAP) 'attempt_201401030639_35106_m_000048_0' to tip task_201401030639_35106_m_000048, for tracker 'tracker_ip-10-0-2-90.aws.novarra.com:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:40109'
2014-01-08 19:53:07,136 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing data-local task task_201401030639_35106_m_000048
2014-01-09 04:10:47,769 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting JobTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ip-10-0-2-91.aws.novarra.com/10.0.2.91
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Log file is definitely the best place to rectify the problem. Please make sure that you are looking into the **.log** file and not into **.out** file. **.out** file doesn't contain the entire log.